# how draw root locus in mathematica 9 for a special case

Tags: plotting, complex

my closed loop transfer function is:

```
H(s)=2exp(-q)/(1+exp(-2q)) 

q=sqrt((a+k*sqrt(s)+s)*s) ,  s=sigma+jw
```

how can i draw root locus of H(s) as 'a' changes for different values of k?
in other words, how can i solve below equation and plot real(s) versus imaginary(s)?

```
1+exp(-2q)==0
```

i need a code for mathematica 9,i have examined some codes, but they didn't work.Tnx All.

Comment: Did you try `RootLocusPlot` and what problem did you encounter? And please write `H(s)` in *Mathematica* code.

Comment: tnx pickett.RootLocusPlot is for analytical transfer functions and is not appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 2):

The root locus is just plot of the zeros of the denominator of the transfer function. So all you have to do is solve that equation for `s` for each `a` (after you fix `k`).

So fix `k`, then for each `a`, find the pole of the transfer function. It will be complex root. Find its real and imaginary part, then use `ListPlot` to plot the data?

```
k = -10;  (*made one up *)
q = Sqrt[(a + k*Sqrt[s] + s)*s]
(*num=2Exp[-q];*) (* not needed*)
den = (1 + Exp[-2 q]);
(*tf=num/den*) (* not needed*)
sol = s /. First@Solve[den == 0, s];
data = Table[{z = sol /. a -> i; Re[z], Im[z]}, {i, 1, 20, .1}]; (*some a data*)
```

Now plot it

```
  ListLinePlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Im(s)", None}, {"Re(s)", "root locus"}}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, Gray}, {Dashed, Gray}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that you'll get

```
    Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions 
    may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information
```

From the Solve or NSolve due to the nature of the equation being solved.

But normally root locus is plotted as gain `k` changes. You are changing `a` which I do not know what it represents.